# How to I decode partially Hex encoded strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, decode, encode

I have a big file with query's like

```
3591018ea0f08b48069ca0ffff640c1cfb.cisco-update.com
dadf018ea058a5ff12a897ffff640c1cfb.cisco-update.com
```

I've put them in a dataframe called df['query']

I've tried multiple decodings

```
    str = df['query'].apply(lambda x: x.encode("latin-1").decode("ascii","ignore"))
str = bytes.fromhex((lambda s: ("%s%s00" * (len(s) // 2)) % tuple(s))(df['query'])).decode('utf-16-le')
```

Error

```
     str = bytes.fromhex((lambda s: ("%s%s00" * (len(s) // 2)) % tuple(s))(df['query'])).decode('utf-16-le')
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I want to decode these query's and be able to partially decode it with hex, or base encodings

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: The expected output is that it actually decodes the query. i have not been able to decode the multiple values in a df, I will get errors like <object at 0x7faaf826e978>

Comment: I meant, what would be the explicit output that matches the provided example?